# Deleting columns at specific position using perl

Tags: perl, parsing, text-files

I am new to Perl and I am trying to delete columns that are defined in specific positions. My file looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/18l5a.png

knowing that the columns are numerated as following:

```
1-3 , 5-7 , 9-12 , 14-16 , 18-21 , 23-25 , 27-29 , 31-37 , 39-68 , 70-72 , 74
```

And I want to delete the columns that start at:

```
1-3 , 14-16 , 23-25 , 27-29 , 31-37 , 39-68 , 70-72 , 74
```

So that I can get this, only the columns: 5-7 and 9-12 but change their positions to: 1-5 and 7-10

I aslo want to add new columns at specific positions, (12-21) for example and get the following resulting file:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQ0Yp.png.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow Imane. Instead of posting image of code, it is always better to add the exact code snippet here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use [`unpack`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html). Try this `perl p.pl < in.txt`, where `p.pl` is:

```
while (<>) {
    my @cols = unpack "A3xA3xA4xA*", $_;
    CORE::say join ' ', $cols[2] . '  ', $cols[1], "      same";
}
```

**Update**:

According to discussion in the comments, the following solution solved the problem:

```
while (<>) {
    my @cols = unpack "A3xA3xA4xA*", $_;
    printf "%-5s %-5s %-4s\n", $cols[1], $cols[2], "same";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but I still have a problem.
You see not all columns have the same length of text, but I still need each column to start at a specific position. 
For example the second column needs to start at the seventh position of the text file no matter what length the text in the first column is.

Comment: Hmm. So you say the first column is from character position 1-3 in your question. Then it will always have length 3, right?

Comment: It starts at 1 and takes maximum 3. So no its length is not necesseraliy 3, it can even be empty.

Comment: Hmm..but then the second column will not start at position 5 any more? If the first column has length zero, the second column will start at position 1 and not 5, right?

Comment: That's the thing, I want the second column to start at its specified position 5 no matter what happens in the previous column...

Comment: But that is how it is working right now. With the script I posted, the second column will always start at column 5 I think?

Comment: I have tested it, and there is always 3 spaces between column 1 and 2, so for example if in column 1 I have nothing the second column starts at the position 3.

Comment: Could you send me the input data you are using? My email is in my profile